# How to save all items from a listview to a textfile

Tags: vb.net

For a school project im making a point of sale program using VB.NET, where you choose a product and its price along with the name of the customer and how they pay (cash mastercard etc)

```
sfile.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    sfile.Filter = ("ONLY Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt")
    sfile.ShowDialog()
    Dim n As New IO.StreamWriter(sfile.FileName)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To lstOutput.Items.Count - 1
        n.WriteLine(lstOutput.Items.Item(i))
```

In the form i have also done

```
dim w as IO.StreamWriter
```

Saving the file does work but it does not come up how i want it

it only comes up with the first column entry for example in the first column the entry is "JOHN SMITH" and it comes up with this

LISTVIEWITEM: {JOHN SMITH}

it should also come up with what he bought, how much it cost, the quantity of items he bought how he payed, and the total price of the items

Also, is there a way, if a customer buys more than one item example he buys a cake and a sandwhich. To sum the amount in the same column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried "lstOutput.Items(i).SubItems(ColumnIndex)"

Comment: where do i put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Dim sfile As New SaveFileDialog
    With sfile
        .Title = "Choose your path to save the information"
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .Filter = ("ONLY Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt")
    End With

    If sfile.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim Write As New IO.StreamWriter(sfile.FileName)
        Dim k As ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection = lstOutput.Columns
        For Each x As ListViewItem In lstOutput.Items
            Dim StrLn As String = ""
            For i = 0 To x.SubItems.Count - 1
                StrLn += k(i).Text + " :" + x.SubItems(i).Text + Space(3)
            Next
            Write.WriteLine(StrLn)
        Next
        Write.Close() 'Or  Write.Flush()
    End If
```

Also, is there a way, if a customer buys more than one item example he buys a cake and a sandwhich. To sum the amount in the same column?

Yes, but give us an example about that field.

Comment: For example i want the program to, after i add the information to my listview, to sum up the total price that John Smith had payed. and if i enter more information it will update that number.

Thanks for the help with the saving, its exactly what i wanted!

Comment: You are welcome, about total price, do you mean that the lstOutput contains many rows with the same name or contains many columns in the same row ?

Answer (score 0):

About total price, Do you mean this ...

```
    Dim ClientName As String = "John"
    Dim IndexOfPrices As Int32 = 1 '// Index Of sub item that contains the item price 


    Dim lstOutput2 As ListView = lstOutput '// Fast loop without access the GUI
    Dim Price As Int32 = 0
    For Each x As ListViewItem In lstOutput2.Items
        Application.DoEvents() '// No need to another thread to do loop inside, DoEvents will solve the problem
        If x.SubItems(0).Text = ClientName Then
            Price += Val(x.SubItems(IndexOfPrices).Text)
        End If
    Next
    lblPrice.Text = "Price :" + Price.ToString + "$"
```